# Compiling .scss to css with grunt returns with weird error

Tags: css, sass, gruntjs, grunt-contrib-sass, grunt-cli

So this is what I have inside of my grunt:

```
concat: {
      css: {
        src: [
          'assets/**.scss.liquid', 'assets/**.css'
        ],
        dest: 'assets/build.scss.liquid',
      }
    },
    sass: {
      dist: {
        options: {
          style: 'compressed',
          sourcemap: 'none',
          noCache: true
        },
        files: {
          'assets/build.css.liquid':'assets/build.scss.liquid'
        }
      }
    }
```

SCSS:

```
.all-collection {
  padding-top: 50px;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  color: white !important;
  justify-content: center;
  display: flex;

  p {
    color: white !important;
  }
}
```

This is what it returns after running `grunt concat` and `grunt sass`:
`Error: Invalid CSS after "50px": expected expression (e.g. 1px, bold), was ";"
        on line 2 of all-collection.scss`

I tried removing the `;` on the line it was specifying but the error just changed to the next line that has `;`. Not sure why it's giving this error.

Comment: what is the SCSS for that line? That means that there is an error in your SCSS, so it can't be compiled

Comment: @JacobGray
<code>
.all-collection {
  padding-top: 50px;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  color: white !important;
  justify-content: center;
  display: flex;

  p {
    color: white !important;
  }
}
</code>

Comment: Can you post that in your question, and show exactly what line is causing the issue?

Comment: @JacobGray updated the post.

Comment: Huh. Is that the whole source of the file? Does it do it on any other files?

Comment: Not the whole source file but the error starts at that line and then keeps on going down each line when I remove the `;` @JacobGray

Comment: How large is the whole source? If it isn't too large, post it. If it is, post the part before that class

Comment: My guess is that you're missing a semicolon before the class declaration, I'll have to see the SCSS to know though

Comment: [Here's the full source of the scss](http://codepen.io/gamalielhere/pen/ZpkAJN) @JacobGray

Comment: Hmm, I don't see anything invalid at the line it says. Have you tried it on other files?

Comment: @JacobGray just did. Still gives the same error about the colon.

Comment: Are you running `concat` before you run `sass`? Try just running sass

Comment: @JacobGray yes so it compiles all of my scss into one file.

Comment: Still gives the same error. @JacobGray

Comment: Okay, get rid of concat, and just link your SCSS files using `@import`

Comment: @JacobGray Seems to really hate ';'. It returned with `Error: Invalid @import: expected end of line, was ";".
        on line 1 of assets/build.scss.liquid`

Comment: @Gamaliel if you paste that portion of your code on its own in another `scss` file, you'll see that it compiles so that's not where the problem is. There's probably an illegal value supplied earlier or a missing semicolon or a form of syntax error that's tripping the way it's being compiled and where sass is identifying the error occurrence

Comment: @BlackEnigma I just switchted to grunt-sass instead. Worked like a charm so I kept it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by switching plugins. I'm using `grunt-sass` instead.